# Saving a File To The Same Directory On Different Computers?

Tags: c#

Okay, so I have written a program, obviously I will be pasting the source code below. I was wondering if there is a simple way to read and write a file, using streamreader/writer from the exact same location on each computer that runs it (as I plan to distribute the program in the future).

I can see why my code at the moment does not work, as I am reading/writing the file in a specific directory, but I need to find a way around this so that the program can save and read the files to a location which is the same on different computers, even if the drives/directories are named differently.

I hope I am making sense, I will post the code below, and this is my first post, so please be kind :D

```
Console.Write("Please Enter Your Username: ");
string getusername = Console.ReadLine();
if (File.Exists("H:\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Server Project\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\" + getusername + ".txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Checking For a {0}.txt file", getusername);
    Console.WriteLine("User Profile '{0}' Found!", getusername);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Checking For a {0}.txt file", getusername);
    Console.WriteLine("That Username / File Path doesn't exist");
}
```

I want my program to check for the file in a default space that can be set using a streamreader/writer function if this is possible, again sorry if this is confusing, I'm new here but I tried to write the post as best I could! Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `on the same location` ? i.e. every computer not necessarily have an `H` drive

Comment: Perhaps something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx Quite a few options!

Comment: you can do `File.Exists(getusername + ".txt")`, but you'd better use special folders as @DanielC said

Comment: You could also use the application directory: [System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry guys, been afk, found my answer, but thanks to all who mentioned special folders, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locations that "are the same on different computers" sounds like [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx).

I.e. for storing "test.txt" in "My documents" path would be:

```
var pathToFile = Path.Combine(
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), 
       "test.txt");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!